# plain present verb + ちょる

Tags: grammar, dialects, role-language

While reading a manga, which takes place during the samurai era, I came across the statement:

> 弟の鉄之助は中岡隊長の言う**ちょった**犯人の特徴とピッタリ合う**ちょるきに**…！

I'm pretty sure it translates roughly to something like

> The younger brother Tetsunosuke matched the description of the culprit given by Captain Nakaoka perfectly!

My question is the meaning of the "ちょった/ちょる" following the verbs as well as the "きに" at the end.

Comment: I also noticed the same pattern several times thereafter but following the masu form of the verb, do they carry the same meaning?

Comment: Note that it doesn't necessarily simply match the ている form in Standard Japanese. 言うちょる or 言っちゅう = "have said", 言いよる or 言いゆう = "is saying"

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia article 「日本の方言」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80#.E7.B6.99.E7.B6.9A.E7.9B.B8.E3.83.BB.E5.AE.8C.E4.BA.86.E7.9B.B8), ～ちょる means ～ている in western dialect. 
It says that they use 「音便形＋ちょる・ちょー」 for ～ている in 島根県出雲, and 「音便形＋ちょる・ちょー」 for ～ている as 完了後の状態を表す相 (perfect aspect) in 岐阜県・奈良県南部・兵庫県播磨・中国地方（出雲除く）・四国地方・九州地方.

And according to [here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80#.E6.8E.A5.E7.B6.9A.E5.8A.A9.E8.A9.9E) in the same article, ～きに is a 接続助詞(conjunctive particle) of 理由(reason) in western dialect. They use 「けん・けー・きん・きー・けに・きに」 in 中国地方・四国地方・九州地方（宮崎県・鹿児島県を除く）.

So [合]{お}うちょるきに means [合]{あ}っているから, and [言]{ゆ}うちょった means [言]{い}っていた.

Comment: Were we all posting more or less the same answer at more or less the same time? :)

Comment: @Tommy そおなんですよ。。。FireFoxで入力してたら、他に回答が投稿されても表示されないから気づかなくって。。。

Answer (score 2):

I looked them up online, and the sources I found (this is one of the sources: http://www.ilovex.co.jp/ilo_week/2007/08/post-117.html) say that

> "ちょった/ちょる” means "ていた/ている”

and

> "きに” means "（のです）から”

So, "合うちょるきに” in your example sentence must be able to be rephrased as "合っている（のです）から", which makes your translation correct. They say that these terms are dialect called 「[土佐弁]{とさべん｝」 spoken mainly in [高知県]{こうちけん} in [四国]{しこく}.

Answer (score 1):

The question got me curious and I made some research.

Apparently ちょる could be a dialectal form of ておる in some areas in western Japan.

Some Japanese people say that this form is commonly used in 山口県, 大分県, and 福岡県 for example (see here http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1165856011).

From the same link you can also get to a Wikipedia page regarding western Japan dialect with more details:

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A5%BF%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80